# weaver throwing BCException in Spring 3.1 MVC project

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, aspectj

I'm trying to implement a finagle server that works with an existing Spring 3.1 MVC project.

I'm able to instantiate the server properly, and it works well - response to messages promptly, doesn't seem to have any trouble living in the Servlet environment.

If I shut down the server during the normal lifetime of the servlet, things go well. However, if I attempt to shut down during the time the app or web context is shutting down (and I've done this in a lot of different places, I get an AspectJ error:

> Jun 22, 2012 12:08:55 PM org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace error
>   SEVERE: scala/collection/JavaConverters$AsScala
>   org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: Whilst processing type
>   'Lscala/collection/JavaConverters$AsScala;' - cannot cast the outer
>   type to a reference type. Signature=Lscala/collection/JavaConverters;
>   toString()=scala.collection.JavaConverters when processing type
>   mungers  when weaving
>
> at org.aspectj.weaver.AbstractReferenceTypeDelegate.g
>   etFormalTypeParametersFromOuterClass(AbstractRefer
>   enceTypeDelegate.java:110) at
>   org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGener
>   icSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:765)

It doesn't help that I don't really know the first thing about how AOP works with Spring.

There are a couple of existing bugs listed for problems with Scala and AspectJ, but I don't think either one is germane. This one was was fixed in AspectJ 1.6.7, and I am using 1.6.9.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339300

I'm wondering if it's possible that this bug is not actually a duplicate, because I think this is what I am seeing:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337064

Can anyone give me some guidance on what is going on here?

Is the right thing to do to simply create an aop.xml that instructs AspectJ to leve all the Scala code alone?

- Mark

Comment: Yes, sounds like the best thing to do would be to keep out the scala related packages from the AspectJ weaver all together, which you can like you pointed out by using an explicit aop.xml file with exclude package names specified